# the space is not resolved and is %20

Tags: javascript, twitter, whitespace

I was trying a tweet button with this script and html code.

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://www.twitter.com/share?
  url=http://www.programworks.co.cc&text=my website">
    <img src = "tweet_button.jpg" />
</a>
```

Now when i click the tweet button this is what i get :

[image]

The link shared is OK but the text that needs to be shared has `%20` for a whitespace. Why is that? How can i remove it ?

Comment: @downvoter Care to drop a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space is encoded as `+`.

You may want to read further [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)